# Parse like functionality best approach

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a "like" functionality to comments. The challenge is finding an efficient way to figure out if the current user has already "liked" a comment or not without having to make an api call for each comment.

Currently I have a User class, Comments class, and Likes class. But I can't seem to find a way to check if the user has already "liked" a comment yet without making extra api calls per comment.

Any suggestions or references would be helpful.

Comment: I was having same problem. At the end I created a column of type relation under Comments class. That relation was pointing at Likes class where I stored all of my likes. Couldn't find any "better" way.

Comment: "Best approach" questions are generally not a good fit for Stack Overflow due to being primarily-opinion based.  Do you have a more specific programming question?

Comment: Yes I understand, but this seems to be a pretty common challenge. I would love to be able to load a set of comments as well as the "like" object for the current user (if they have liked the comment already).

Comment: I did this functionality that I created array filed on the Comment PFObject (just array of Strings) and I store objectID of the users that Liked the Comment, everytime the Comment is downloaded it downloads this array too and just check if the PFUser.currentuser() is equal to one of those elements in that array.... I suppose my comments will have 100 Likes maximum so there wont be any Performance issues, but if you expect more I would find better solution than this...

Comment: Yes, I've thought about resorting to that. If you have an app that is getting more than 100 likes per comment, business is good. Just trying to find the most scaleable way to do this. If I ever got to that point, that is probably a small matter :)

Comment: @MazelTov 's implementation is only solution for what you want. But as he mentions, comment with likes limitation. A parse object has max size, so that the array cannot scale once reach the size limit. If regardless additional one api call, relation is more suitable implementation, and maintain the local cache of what current user have liked.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting question and each answer has influence to the general performance and possibility to implement;

For me, I would create data base with relations one-to-many between user and comment entities;
When data is loading from the internet(as an example) there are comments relating to current user + It would be good to have additional field in comment entity called *"isLiked"* or something.

Comment: "one-to-many" usually means pointer, in this case should be many-to-many. One User have multiple like to comment, and comments have multiple Users like.